# SharedPreferences ToggleButton not saving

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

*I've been going nuts with this problem the last few days.I'm trying to use SharedPreferences to allow my users to save the selected option of the in-game audio via the ToggleButton but everytime when I run my app and hit my "Done" button to go back to the main_activity screen and then click on settings again it never saves.I've done some research on this by googling,my book and this site but by many methods I've tried the result is the same.
I'm new to android development let alone app development so as much as I learned these past few weeks this has been a major roadblock for me and I apologize if this question has been covered already on this site but I'm at a real loss on what I'm doing wrong here.
Here is my code from my settings activity.

```
package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;    

public class Settings extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);  

        Button Notifications = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Notifications);
        Button Done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
        Button AccountSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AccountSettings);
        final ToggleButton AT = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.AudioToggle);
        AT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                {
                    if ((AT.isChecked()))
                    {
                        SharedPreferences appPrefs =
                        getSharedPreferences("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Settings_preferences",
                                        MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("atpref", AT.isChecked()); //value to store
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        SharedPreferences appPrefs =
                getSharedPreferences("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Settings_preferences",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean atpref = appPrefs.getBoolean("atpref", true); //default is true
        AT.setChecked(atpref);
        Done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent Intent = new Intent(Settings.this,activity_main.class);
                Intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(Intent);



            }
        });
        Notifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Notifications"));
            }
        });
        AccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.AccountSettings"));
            }
        });

    }    

    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        // Is the toggle on?
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

        if (on) {
            view.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
        } else {
            view.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you can change the default value from true to false. or you can go with @Sam 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to save the ToggleButton's state when it is `false`, simply remove the if-statement in your OnClickListener:

```
if ((AT.isChecked()))
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me!Would of never figured this out and I learned alot from your answer!